# How to get the latest file from a fileshare by using ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

The files which gets loaded in my file share are like below and each day the data are getting loaded:-
xyz_activation_2021-11-06T00-01-13.csv
xyz_activation_2021-11-07T00-01-13.csv
xyz_activation_2021-11-08T00-01-13.csv

So now how can i get the latest date record in my pipeline using ADF.

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Create Pipeline

**Step2:** Select Get Metadata activity

**Step3:**

[image]

**Step4:** In Get Metadata activity select Child Items to loop through your folder.

[image]

**Step5:** Select ForEach activity.

**Step6:** Inside ForEach Activity create Second Get Metadata activity.
Also Create 2 arguments as Item.Name and Last Modified.

[image]

**Step7:** Now create If Condition activity.

Inside If Condition activity use

```
@greater(formatDateTime(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified,'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), formatDateTime(variables('LatestModifiedDate'),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
```

expression for True condition.

[image]

**Step8:** Create SetVariable activity and Use below expression.

```
@activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified
```

[image]

**Step9:** In last step I used Copy Activity to copy last created file from one container to another container.
[image]

This is my Input Container

[image]

This is my Output Container.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. Helped to build the pipeline.

Comment: @subhamdas if my answer is useful please accept it as answer (click on check mark on left side of answer) to help other community members.